# How to write a function that returns a script as a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular and I want to append a script to the template of my directive. I want to accomplish this by writing a function that accepts the parameters the script needs and then returning it as a string. I would like to do it this way so that I dont have to write long javascript files as strings.

I have the following directive:

## directive

```
 function barchart() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            template: `
                  <div id="canvas" class ="panel-body container-fluid">
                    <div class ="ui centered grid">
                        <div>
                            <div id="title"></div>
                            <div id="chart"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                `,
            scope: {
                revenues: "=revenues"
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch('revenues', function (rev) {

                    if (typeof rev != 'undefined') {
                        $element.append(`<script> (render(${rev}))(); </script>`);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I want something around these lines, but it doesn't work

## render *(function that should return a script)*

```
function render(params){
   return (function(){
            $('#chart').append('<p> params </p>');
          })();
}
```

## error

```
rev is not defined
```

Comment: `${render(rev)}`

Comment: btw... `render` doesn't return a script in the snippet you've provided. It returns undefined ater executing the IIFE.

Comment: @KevinB This is what I want to learn how to do. What I have is my attempt at making something that creates a script from a function and its parameters. How would I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure. to me this seems like a reallly bad idea, why can't you just... execute the code rather than trying to inject it into your page, which would simply execute the code?

Answer (score 0):

Surround `render()` call with `${`, `}`

```
$element.append(`<script>${render(rev)}</script>`);
```

Comment: I still get `rev is not defined`. I console.logged rev before that line and rev has the data you'd expect it to have

Comment: Can you create a plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate? Note `render` returns `undefined` as no value is returned from the IIFE within `render` function. Is `<p> params </p>` appended to `#chart` element? What is expected result?

Comment: something like this https://plnkr.co/edit/4brDVy3rJk5yJVTMadJV?p=preview although on my end $watch works just fine, but in this plunker it doesn't

Comment: Am not familiar with `angularjs`. What is `rev` expected to be? The code at plnkr is different from code at Question. Is `rev` expected to be the result of an asynchronous function call?

Comment: rev is a json objectt it could be anything. In the plunker I'm using placeholder data

Comment: Yes, why are you expecting `rev` to be result of `promise = $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');`?